# Group By Statuses using reduce

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been using `reduce()` method to group by Open and Closes statuses (`Status_111`, `Status_222`, etc) which then creates an array of which Ids (`item.Id`) it is associated with.

Code is working and with an expected result, however, I feel like code could have been written better because as you can see I have been using too many if conditions for creating blank arrays to check `if (item.Open && !obj[item.Open])` and `if (item.Close && !obj[item.Close])` exists - how would you improve the code?

```js
const items = [
  { Id: 100, Open: 'Status_111', Close: 'Status_111' },
  { Id: 200, Open: 'Status_111', Close: 'Status_222' },
  { Id: 300, Open: 'Status_333', Close: 'Status_444' }
]

function groupByOpenAndClose(items) {
  return items.reduce(function (obj, item) {
    if (item.Open && !obj[item.Open]) {
        obj[item.Open] = {
          Open: [],
          Close: []
        }
    }

    if (item.Close && !obj[item.Close]) {
      obj[item.Close] = {
        Open: [],
        Close: []
      }
    }

    if (obj[item.Open]) {
      obj[item.Open].Open.push(item.Id)
    }

    if (obj[item.Close]) {
      obj[item.Close].Close.push(item.Id)
    }

    return obj
  }, {});
}

console.log(groupByOpenAndClose(items));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
function groupByOpenAndClose(items) {
  return items.reduce((obj, item) => {
    return {
      ...obj,
      [item.Close]: {
        Close: [...(obj[item.Close]?.Close ?? []), item.Id],
        Open: obj[item.Close]?.Open ?? []
      },
      [item.Open]: {
        Open: [...(obj[item.Open]?.Open ?? []), item.Id],
        Close: obj[item.Open]?.Close ?? []
      }
    }
  }, {});
}
```

But in all seriousness, it is not much you can do without creating some structure of your own - something like default dict in python:

```
class DefaultDict {
  constructor(defFactory) {
    this.defFactory = defFactory;
    this.dict = {}
  }
  
  getOrDefault(status) {
    if(!status) return;
    if(!this.dict[status]) this.dict[status] = this.defFactory();
    
    return this.dict[status];
  }
}

function groupByOpenAndClose(items) {
  return items.reduce(function(obj, item) {
    obj.getOrDefault(item.Close)?.Close.push(item.Id);
    obj.getOrDefault(item.Open)?.Open.push(item.Id);
    return obj;
  }, new DefaultDict(() => ({ Close: [], Open: [] })));
}

console.log(groupByOpenAndClose(items).dict);
```